# Filtering data in sql for each month from a date field

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables are:

```
customer(cid,name,city,state)
orders(oid,cid,date)
product(pid,productname,price)
lineitem(lid,pid,oid,number,totalprice)
```

I want to create a view ProductMonth `(PID, ProductName, Month, QuantitySold, NumberCus­tomer, Revenue)` that gives for each the product and each month, the quantity sold, the
number of distinct customers who bought the product and amount of money the sale
corresponds to for the month.

I used `extract()` to get the months from `orders.date`. I need to know how to loop each month and each product. I couldn't come up with a working query. Is it even possible to do it in MySQL? I mean looping the product name for each month and calculating the total price and also how much each product sales contributed to the whole. I know how to implement this for a particular product or month but not for products sold in each month. I tried using joins but it fails. I need the query and also a logic to implement it.

Comment: It is certainly possible but loops are unnecessary. Although many SQL dialects, MySQL included, do have loops, the language (SQL) has never been about looping but about working with whole sets (subsets). It might be easier (and possibly more beneficial for you) if we used your own attempts as a starting point to try and help you to grasp thinking in sets. Please show your query that can calculate the totals for a single product/month pair. And it would be really great if you also added a data sample to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that lineitem.number is the number of units sold.

```
SELECT  P.pid
,p.productname
,Month=datepart(mm, O.date)
,QuantitySold = sum(L.number)
,NumberCustomer = count(distinct cid)
,Revenue = sum(L.totalprice)
FROM orders O 
JOIN customer C on C.cid = O.cid
JOIN lineitem L on L.oid = O.oid
JOIN product P on P.pid = L.pid
GROUP BY
 P.pid
,p.productname
,Month=datepart(mm, O.date)
```

Comment: This also assumes Transact-SQL, as far as I can see, but the OP is using MySQL.

Comment: Once I change the datepart() function to extract() it works fine.Thank you.